# vba excel copy only visible cells on key press ctrl+c

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel with 75 columns and some thousands of rows of data. Out of 75 columns I am using 5 columns for my vba coding purpose. These 5 columns hold flags (either `0` or `1`) based on which I am locking the cells in the corresponding row (*Flags are coming from Database*). As user doesn't want these flag columns I just hid those columns but when ever user tries to copy data from my workbook to another workbook user is able to copy the hidden columns which client doesn't want.

So is there anyway to restrict them not to copy the hidden columns through **VBA** or with any setting? Actually for this issue what I thought is like on key press of <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>, I tried to change the `Selection.Copy` as `Selection.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. But I am getting some error like `wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`.

The lines of code is

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Application.OnKey "^c", "Copy"
End Sub

Sub Copy()
    If Selection Is Nothing Then
    Else
        Selection.Copy = Selection.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas to restrict users not to copy the hidden columns. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.Copy
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Number : " & Err.Number
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

**Note**: I have used Error Handling which is a must because the user might select non contiguous ranges and the code will break if the error handling is not done :) See Screenshot below

[image]

Comment: in my sheets there are some merged cells. when i ever i tried to copy them along with normal cells it is giving me error like `Can't change part of merged cell`. In our application user can copy merged cells also.

Comment: One more problem that i got with that code is when i press **ctrl+c** in other workbooks that key press is calling my `sub Copy`. Actually i want to run that code only for my workbook but not for other workbooks. Please help me.

Comment: I am able to copy merged cells and normal cells with no problem :) Regarding your other query, it is but natural as you are setting it at the `Application` level. Try to reset `Application.OnKey "^c", ""` in the `Workbook_Deactivate` event and set it back in the 'Workbook_Activate' event?

Comment: i have read some where like if we run macro or inbuilt function that will remove clipboard data. In that case if we place code in `workbook_Deactivate` it clears clipboard data. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You first comment is partially true. The clipboard is cleared only when you perform certain action for example clear cells or write to cells. The clipboard will not get empty if the macro just shows a MessageBox. So it again depends what have you placed in `workbook_Deactivate`