# vba excel copy only visible cells on key press ctrl+c for protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to replace ctrl+c so it will copy only visible cells on a protected sheet. Trying to solve this problem I stumbled on this post ([vba excel copy only visible cells on key press ctrl+c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784284/vba-excel-copy-only-visible-cells-on-key-press-ctrlc))

The following code (suggested by Siddharth-Rout) works but only for a non-protected sheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Application.OnKey "^c", "Copy"
End Sub

Sub Copy()
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.Copy
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Number : " & Err.Number
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

I tried unprotecting, copying, and then reprotecting but it removes the copy. I need the final sheet to be protected. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah! A blast from the past :P

You need to unprotect and protect just before you copy. Also I am using `ActiveSheet` for demonstration purpose. Change that to the relevant sheet if required.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim MyPassword As String

    '~~> Change password as applicable
    MyPassword = "Sid"

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect MyPassword
        Set rng = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ActiveSheet.Protect MyPassword

        rng.Copy
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Number : " & Err.Number
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting. ActiveSheet.Unprotect/Protect worked like a charm but Worksheets("Example").Unprotect/Protect was giving me issue. Thanks a lot for your quick help!